# Mounting file based file system in windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, mount

I am looking to find a suitable file system and mount it in windows 10. Normally this file should be detected as just as a file in windows. But on executing some commands/UI, I should be able to mount the file's file system with reading and preferably write support.
I am looking for suggestions for this setup.

thanks,
gl

Comment: Perhaps using a vhd file would satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used virtual disk files for this purpose. One common format is the VHD file type. When unmounted, it appears to Windows simply as a file. Once mounted, it can be formatted in NTFS or FAT32. They can be fixed size or dynamic. A dynamic VHD is created small (just a header and footer) and grows as data is added. If data is deleted from a dynamic VHD, it does not shrink automatically, but tools are available to do this. Maximum VHD size is 2 TB, but the successor VHDX format can be up to 64 TB.

[VHD file format (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHD_(file_format))